# dinosaur visibility range

Tags: jurassic-world-alive

sometimes dinosaurs appear when they enter my radius (I enter their radius actually) and my phone vibrates to alert me,

sometimes dinosaurs are visible in the distance and I can travel to them but get no vibration alert when they enter my radius

what causes this difference?

Answer (score 1):

I have two theories:

1. it is your personal spawn or
2. it is movement triggered spawn.

It also vibrates when using scent.